# JQuery addClass and removeClass works but will not function properly at certain window size

Tags: jquery, addclass, removeclass

I want to addClass and removeClass on different screen size. I've done the jQuery and it basically works when the window resize. However, at a certain pixel, roughly around 764px, the  layout shows that the removeClass function works but the addClass function is not working. How can I make it works? Below is my code. Thanks a bunch!

```
function checkWindowSize() {
    if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-vertical").addClass("newslider-horizontal");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').removeClass('featured');
    } else {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-horizontal").addClass("newslider-vertical");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').addClass('featured');
    }
}
$(window).load(checkWindowSize);
$(window).resize(checkWindowSize);
```

Comment: you may want to log (debug) in console .hasClass value for your div and see whether it actually adds class to element?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(window).on('load',function(){
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-vertical").addClass("newslider-horizontal");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').removeClass('featured');
    } else {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-horizontal").addClass("newslider-vertical");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').addClass('featured');
    }
});



$(window).on('resize',function(){
if ($(window).width() < 767) {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-vertical").addClass("newslider-horizontal");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').removeClass('featured');
    } else {
        $("div.sliderkit").removeClass("newslider-horizontal").addClass("newslider-vertical");
        $('.highlight article ul li:first-child').addClass('featured');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I tried. It works when I continously resize the window. However, when the screen is loaded at the size smaller than 767px, the function does not work anymore. I need it to work onload also because I am targeting on different screen sizes mobile devices.

Comment: Still the same. At a point, the removeClass function works but addClass function not working.

Comment: Still the same. Is it because of the css problem? in my CSS, I use @media all and (max-width: 767px){}. I did try to change the ($(window).width() < 767) to ($(window).width() <= 767) but still not working. I have another media queries for screen 768 to 1200.